# How to centering Content

Tags: css, wordpress, margin

I make some homepage using wordpress.

i use this css code

```
.container { width: 960px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;  }
```

actually looking good, content's position is center.

but sometimes change content, change margin

my resolution is 1920 width, content's width is 960px fixed.

content 1 has 960px width and  margin is 475.75px
content 2 has 960px width and margin is 480px

i want 480px fixed.

what is problem?

Comment: Do you see any other style when you inspect the element ?

Comment: yes I use table with tinyMCE advanced
delete table, then margin is 480px but using table then 475.75px

Comment: I found real problem

using long heights contents, appear scrollbar, then calculating margin .. this is problem

Comment: using always show scrollbar
html{overflow-y : scroll;}

Comment: have you tried margin: 0 auto; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add content1 half the width of container , give margin auto .

.content1 { width:475x; margin:auto; word-wrap:break-word;}